# HTML character to break long word at specific point

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Is there an encoded character in HTML that allows a word to break at a specific point, but not create a space if it is not required?

For instance, I want to show a full URL such as the following if the space allows it...

```
http://www.example.com/mylongpagename
```

But if showing in a small area (for instance on a mobile screen) I want to split it between the `/` and `my` so that it automatically wraps as...

```
http://www.example.com/
mylongpagename
```

I'm aware of the CSS command of `word-wrap: break-word;` but that could end up as something like...

```
http://www.example.com/mylongpa
gename
```

Comment: I was too quick to accept this duplication - I used the `<wbr>` in the end.  I have voted to reopen

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [`<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) HTML element. It specifies a "word break opportunity", meaning it will break at that point only if needed (e.g., on small screens).

So in your example you could do something such as:

```
<p>http://www.example.com/<wbr>mylongpagename</p>
```

Comment: Ack, I accepted the "duplicate" too quickly... I think this is a better/neater solution

Comment: Is there a way for browsers to then automatically add a hyphen at the end of the word break?
EDIT: Ok I just found out `&shy;` does just that!