# Break long word at specific point in React Native

Tags: react-native, line-breaks, word-break

I am relatively new to React Native and styling with flex and have been looking for a way to break a long word at a specific point. I only want an *optional* break in case the word gets too long.
In case 1 (see example) I don't want to break the word, since the component is big enough.
In case 2 the component is too small so the word breaks. I would like to be able to control the breaking position to get something as in case 3.

I am looking for something similar to this [solution for HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592045/html-character-to-break-long-word-at-specific-point), but I cannot use `<wbr>` or `&#8203;` and could not find an equivalent for React Native, if something like that exists.
I have tried using `\u00AD` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894912/react-native-hyphenation), but it doesn't seem to insert a break.

Example:

```
// case1
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
|ReallyLongWordThatBreaksSomewhere           |
|                                            |
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

// case2
–––––––––––––––––––––––
|ReallyLongWordThatBre|
|aksSomewhere         |
|                     |
–––––––––––––––––––––––

// case3
–––––––––––––––––––––––
|ReallyLongWord       |
|ThatBreaks           |
|Somewhere            |
–––––––––––––––––––––––
```

Comment: have you tried using `word` , i.e using backticks to break the line?

Comment: it's not clear well i think, if you need to break a static string , just try like <Text>{"React \n Native"}</Text>

Comment: @turninglights...you need the long string just like this ???
String :- "the name is john"
Breaked String :- "the name......."

Comment: I edited my question for clarification. I am looking for an optional break, so I cannot use static breaks like `\n`.

Comment: I realised a mistake that I've been making. `&#8203;` should not be wrapped in curly brackets. Placed directly in `<Text>` works for me now. Although, in my case I have also Chinese characters, for which there doesn't seem to be a solution.